# Why context.WithTimeout sometimes fail

Tags: go, concurrency, timeout

I have been trying to implement a timeout logic using `context.WithTimeout` function:

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
CPU: Intel® Core™ i5-10300H CPU @ 2.50GHz × 8
Go Version: go version go1.18.2 linux/amd64
```

```golang
package internal

import (
    "context"
    "errors"
    "time"
)

var (
    ErrTimeout         = errors.New("timeout error")
    ErrFuncTimeProcess = errors.New("function time process error")
)

func Timeout(timeout, funcTimeProcess time.Duration) error {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), timeout)
    defer cancel()

    callDone := make(chan struct{}, 1)
    go doCall(callDone, funcTimeProcess)

    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        return ErrTimeout
    case <-callDone:
        return ErrFuncTimeProcess
    }
}

func doCall(c chan<- struct{}, timeout time.Duration) {
    time.Sleep(timeout)
    c <- struct{}{}
}
```

And I have a test implemented like that:

```golang
package internal_test

import (
    "testing"
    "time"

    "github.com/edualb/bubble/internal"
)

func TestTimeout(t *testing.T) {
    err := internal.Timeout(10*time.Millisecond, 11*time.Millisecond)
    if err != internal.ErrTimeout {
        t.Errorf("unexpected error. wants timeout error, got: %v", err)
    }
}
```

When I try to run the command test below, sometimes I got success and other I got fail:

```bash
# -race: built-in data race detector
# -cpu: Specify a list of GOMAXPROCS values for which the tests, benchmarks or fuzz tests should be executed.
# -count: Run each test, benchmark, and fuzz seed n times (default 1). 
# -failfast: Do not start new tests after the first test failure.
$ go test ./... -cpu=1,9 -race -count=50 -failfast
```

Result:
[image: Terminal print with golang tests]

I don't know what I am doing wrong in this implementation and I would like to ask help for the community to understand that. Thanks.

Comment: Timing, especially on Windows is not arbitrary precise. Neither time.Sleep nor context.WithTimeout make reliable statements on how exact they are (consult the docs): You test is flawed. Use 1s and 2s.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Volker. I couldn't find this information on context pkg doc neither on time pkg doc. Can you share it with us?

Comment: "go doc time.Sleep
package time // import "time"

func Sleep(d Duration)
    Sleep pauses the current goroutine for **at least** the duration d. A negative
    or zero duration causes Sleep to return immediately." [emph. mine]

Comment: "I couldn't find this information" exactly. There _is_ no documented guaranty how precise this stuff is. This you must not assume some (especially low) precision.

Comment: In fact, I found more information about time precision in each OS. I think the comments above helped me to interpret the Go documentation better too. Thanks a lot for the clarification @Volker!